# Axios post request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am getting a status code 400 for the following request but it's working fine in postman.

```
function App() {
  function sendRequest(){
    let body={
        client_id: 'val1',
        client_secret: 'val2',
        code: '12345',
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: 'exp://127.0.0.1:19000'
    };
    let config = {
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    }
    axios.post('https://www.example.com',body,config).then((res)=>{
      console.log("The response is: "+res)
    }).catch(err=>console.log("The error is: "+err))
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <button onClick={()=>sendRequest()} >Run</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the output on console I am getting, `The error is: Error: Request failed with status code 400`

Comment: ` 'Content-Type': 'application/json' ` please try with contet-type application json.

Comment: Another common mistake can be this: on postman you're doing a `post` or a `get`?

Comment: Are you really sure sending to `example.com`? If you own the server code you should also post it here too. Otherwise, tell us what request you're trying to aim for?

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
function App() {
      function sendRequest(){
        let params =new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('client_id','val1');
        params.append('client_secret','val2');
        params.append('code','12345');
        params.append('grant_type','authorization_code');
        params.append('redirect_uri','exp://127.0.0.1:19000');
        axios.post('https://www.example.com',params).then((res)=>{
          console.log("The response is: "+res)
        }).catch(err=>console.log("The error is: "+err))
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
         <button onClick={()=>sendRequest()} >Run</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
```